# Does DataTable.NewRow do anything other than return a row?

Tags: c#, datatable, refactoring

I see this a lot in some new code I've inherited:

`DataRow row = Method.dtContainer.NewRow();`

But then row is never added to the table or even used after that. ReSharper shows it as grey and safe to remove. However, should I remove the entire line or just the variable assigning? Anotherwords, does calling NewRow do anything to the table or does it just return a new object that can then later be added to the `DataTable`? I've checked and it isn't accessed anywhere else through reflection, gotos, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper is right.

[`NewRow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) just returns a new row that has the structure(schema) of the `DataTable` instance.

Usually, the new row is populated with data and added to the `DataTable`, like so:

```csharp
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

If it is not used in any way, it's safe to remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

try to run this code:

```
    var table = new DataTable();

    while(true)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
    }
```

If Resharper was right, it wouldn't throw OutOfMemoryException!